# Looping for specific values on a df

Tags: python, pandas

On one side I have a massive `df`:

```
df1

                A     B    C    ....
2005-11-01     5.3   22    6
2005-11-02     5.4   21    4 
2005-11-03     5.2   17    7
   ....
```

On the other hand I have a smaller df with the following structure;

```
df2

       date       
A    2005-11-02  
B    2005-11-01
C    2005-11-03
```

What I am looking forward to is to add an additional column in `df2` called price which loops over each index value and column value from df2 and look for the corresponding prices in `df` .

The desired output would be something like this:

```
       date        price
A    2005-11-02     5.4
B    2005-11-01      22
C    2005-11-03      7
```

I tried :

```
prices=[]

for index,column in df2:
    prices.append(df.loc[column['date'][i],index.iloc[i]])
    i+=1
return prices
```

However returns this undesired output.

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Could anyone tell me how could I loop through `df` based on the index and column from `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df.lookup(df2.date,df2.index)
Out[1003]: array([  5.4,  22. ,   7. ])
```

After assign it back

```
df2['Value']=df.lookup(df2.date,df2.index)
df2
Out[1005]: 
         date  Value
A  2005-11-02    5.4
B  2005-11-01   22.0
C  2005-11-03    7.0
```

Comment: Yup, this is definitely how I'd do it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I feel the way you provided is faster than `lookup `

Answer (score 2):

`lookup` is the right way to do it. For reference, you were on the right track, but it would've been better to use `iteritems`, or `zip` the index and values:

```
df2['Values'] = [df.loc[j, i] for i, j in df2['date'].iteritems()]

df2

         date  Values
A  2005-11-02     5.4
B  2005-11-01    22.0
C  2005-11-03     7.0
```